# Connect Lilypad to LCD

Tags: lcd

I am trying to connect an LCD panel (RioRand (TM) IIC/I2C/TWI Serial 2004 20x4 LCD Module Shield For Arduino UNO MEGA R30) to a Lilypad Arduino.  How can I get them to talk to each other?   I cannot figure out how to connect them.

Comment: Looks like you have to learn what is I2C and where is I2C in Arduino Lilypad.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to look that up and I got it to light up.  Cannot seem to get Hello World to work with the program in the tutorial.  I am new to all of this.